# Convert to different positional notation in Python 3

Tags: python, numbers

I'm trying to write a function that allows me to convert a number from a certain positional notation to another one of choice, from binary all the way to **hexa**trigesimal base numbers. In order to do so I first need to be able to convert my initial number (given as a string) to a decimal number to make further conversion easier.

However, my function appears to have a mistake.

What I have:

```
def decimal(number, base1):
    number_dec = 0
    val = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    if base1 != 10:
        for digit in number[::-1]:
            factor = val.find(digit)
            for exp in range(0, len(number)):
                number_dec += factor * base1 **exp
    else:
        number_dec = number
    return number_dec
```

If I enter, for instance:

```
decimal('4d2', 16)
```

The function returns '5187' instead of the correct '1234'.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: (+1) for *pentatrigesimal* :)

Comment: Unless you're doing this as homework/self-teaching/etc., the built-in [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function already does this: `int('4d2', 16)` returns `1234`, and `int('4x3', 36)` returns `6375`. (It only works up to base 36, but then the same is true of your code, and if "pentatrigesimal" is the limit of what you need, you're done.) Also, it works with capital letters as well as lowercase.

Comment: Also, your code returns an integer if `base1 != 10`, but a string if it is. That's probably not what you wanted, is it?

Comment: It's a tiny part of my homework I need to attack a bigger problem indeed. But I do notice that the function repeats the loop three times per individual digit as NPE pointed out. That is the mistake.

Comment: @DennyNuyts: Yes, if your question was "what's wrong with my code?", NPE has answered it. If your question was "how do I convert strings representing numbers from base 2 up to 35 into integers?", the answer is "just use `int`."

Comment: The base1 input is supposed to be an integer. Only number has to be a string. :)

Comment: @DennyNuyts: Right, but if `base1` is `10`, you just do `number_dec = number` and then return that—so you're returning a string. If it's anything else, you're calculating an integer in `number_dec` and returning that.

Comment: One minor nitpick: `decimal` is the name of a module that comes with Python, so it's generally not a good name to use for a top-level function.

Comment: I see. I need to convert the number_dec to an integer, as it's needed for the other function that follows. Good point.

Comment: Well, I'm using decimaal (in Dutch), but I translated everything in English, so no worries there.

Comment: Anyway, I'm just using `int`. No need to extra headaches. I might find out the correct algorithm in due time. Thanks for your quick responses. They really help this newbie out.

Answer (score 1):

You perform the entire loop *for every digit*:

```
    for exp in range(0, len(number)):
        number_dec += factor * base1 **exp
```

If you don't *have* to roll out your own, you could just use the built-in facility:

```
In [2]: int('4d2', 16)
Out[2]: 1234
```

Comment: Well, 2 * 16^0 + 13 * 16^1 + 4 * 16^2 happens to equal 1234. Three hexadecimal digits. That is what I intend the loop to do.

Comment: I do need to be able to convert any number I give in from every base possible.

Comment: @DennyNuyts: Once again, you repeat the entire loop three times.

Comment: I see. You meant the inner loop. Gosh. Thanks for opening my eyes. Haha. Problem might be solved. Thanks again.